# Simple inheritance with mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, inheritance

I have this extension method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString BenefitURL(this HtmlHelper Html
                                           , DTOBaseBenefit benefit)
    {

        string title = **(benefit is DTOBenefitButtonText)** ? 
                       ((DTOBenefitButtonText)benefit).ButtonText : 
                       benefit.BenefitTitle;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(benefit.FileURL))
        {
            return Html.ActionLink(title, 
                                   "GetBenefit", 
                                   new { benefitID = benefit.BenefitID });
        }

        var url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
        return Html.ActionLink(benefit.BenefitTitle, 
                               url.Content(benefit.FileURL));
    }
```

In the view I have this:

```
@model  IEnumerable<WellfareSystem.Entities.ViewModels.DTOBenefitButtonText> 
.
.
.
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
     @Html.BenefitURL(Model.Skip(i).First())
    }
```

Now:

```
 public class DTOBenefitButtonText : DTOBaseBenefit
 {
 ....
 }
```

** Question: In my ext. method the cast check of (benefit is DTOBenefitButtonText) return FALSE. while it shoudn't since I pass DTOBenefitButtonText to the method. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you debug to that point, what type does it say `benefit` is? (if you add a watch, or quick watch the variable in the debugger).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
benefit.GetType() == typeof(DTOBenefitButtonText)
```